# Why I can't receive next messages without deleting previous in SQS queue using c++

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-sqs

I have the following example, where I'm trying to receive messages from **SQS** queue.
I can successfully get first batch of messages, but after that, the function **ReceiveMessage()** returns only an empty messages.
If I delete all received messages after every call of  **ReceiveMessage()** I can see next messages.

So I want to know why?
Because as I understand after receiving messages, they are going to in-flight mod,
so when I call **ReceiveMessage()** again, I should get the next batch of messages without calling **delete**

Thank You

```
Aws::Vector<Aws::SQS::Model::Message> receive_message() const
{
    Aws::SQS::Model::ReceiveMessageRequest rm_req;
    rm_req.SetQueueUrl(queue_url_);
    rm_req.SetMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    rm_req.SetWaitTimeSeconds(20);

    const Aws::SQS::Model::ReceiveMessageOutcome rm_out = sqs_client_->ReceiveMessage(rm_req);

    if (false == rm_out.IsSuccess())
    {
        throw;
    }

    Aws::Vector<Aws::SQS::Model::Message> messages = rm_out.GetResult().GetMessages();
    return messages;
}
    
int main()
{
    AmazonSQSReceiver sqs_receiver(Global::queue_name);

    while (true)
    {
        Aws::Vector<Aws::SQS::Model::Message> messages = sqs_receiver.receive_message();
        
        for (const auto &message : messages)
        {
            const Aws::String &message_body = message.GetBody();
            std::cout<< message_body << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this sounds strange but just keep trying to get messages.  SQS only really works by polling - and polling often.  You won't get all of the messages in the queue without calling `ReceiveMessage` multiple times.  It's the same in every programming language I've used with SQS.

Comment: @stdunbar I call `ReceiveMessage` many times, but I don't get messages until I remove the previous ones, or after 2 minutes I get the same messages. It is also strange, My visibility timeout is 30